# I have installed linux on my system and I wanted to install git

Tags: git

How to install git in linux and how to work with git?

Comment: Have a look at this link - http://git-scm.com/download/linux

Comment: Installing `git` is the same as installing any package, and you didn't even mention which distro you're using, so unless you're having specific problems this is too broad

Answer (score 3):

Just install like any other package using your Linux distribution's package management. Command-line that would be something like

```
yum install git
```

for Fedora/RedHat/CentOS based distributions,

```
apt-get install git
```

for Debian/Ubuntu based distributions.

Consult your distribution's documentation on how to install packages. I'm sure it provides the very common `git` package. :)

Then on how to use git, use the general Git documentation, for example start reading ["1.3 Getting Started - Git Basics"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics).